# Electron threw a compile error and Windows command prompt goes non writable

Tags: npm, cmd, compiler-errors, electron, npm-start

So my code had an invalid syntax, which I was trying out to see if it works and while compiling I got `App threw an error during load`.

Now in the `command-prompt` the error is listed in detail with the cursor still **blinking** but **NOT WRITABLE**. Closing, re-opening, re-navigating and restarting with `electron .` only seems to work.

Can't do the same for many errors I might face. So, is there a way to not let that happen? How are you guys dealing with it? Is it in anyway connected to `stopping` the `npm server`? If it helps, I'm using a Win 7 64bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way, which is to terminate the `batch` job by hitting <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>, which asks `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` where choosing `Y` **terminates** and makes the command prompt writable.

I was searching for methods to terminate without confirmation and [learnt](https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation) it cannot be terminated without confirmation.